# Why does this TinyOS C code file appear obfuscated?

Tags: c, tinyos

I've received a 2 MB code file for a device based on TinyOS and it appears that some application has consolidated all of the original code files into one but it moves lines all around.  Do you know what generated this file and how to extract it?

Here's the first couple hundred lines of the app.c provided:

```
#define nx_struct struct
#define nx_union union
#define dbg(mode, format, ...) ((void)0)
#define dbg_clear(mode, format, ...) ((void)0)
#define dbg_active(mode) 0
# 150 "/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/include/stddef.h" 3
typedef long int ptrdiff_t;
#line 212
typedef unsigned int size_t;
#line 324
typedef int wchar_t;
# 8 "/usr/lib/ncc/deputy_nodeputy.h"
struct __nesc_attr_nonnull {
#line 8
  int dummy;
}  ;
#line 9
struct __nesc_attr_bnd {
#line 9
  void *lo, *hi;
}  ;
#line 10
struct __nesc_attr_bnd_nok {
#line 10
  void *lo, *hi;
}  ;
#line 11
struct __nesc_attr_count {
#line 11
  int n;
}  ;
#line 12
struct __nesc_attr_count_nok {
#line 12
  int n;
}  ;
#line 13
struct __nesc_attr_one {
#line 13
  int dummy;
}  ;
#line 14
struct __nesc_attr_one_nok {
#line 14
  int dummy;
}  ;
#line 15
struct __nesc_attr_dmemset {
#line 15
  int a1, a2, a3;
}  ;
#line 16
struct __nesc_attr_dmemcpy {
#line 16
  int a1, a2, a3;
}  ;
#line 17
struct __nesc_attr_nts {
#line 17
  int dummy;
}  ;
# 38 "/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/../../../../msp430/include/stdint.h" 3
typedef signed char int8_t;
typedef int int16_t;
typedef long int int32_t;
__extension__ 
#line 41
typedef long long int int64_t;

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int uint16_t;
typedef unsigned long int uint32_t;
__extension__ 
#line 46
typedef unsigned long long int uint64_t;


typedef signed char int_least8_t;
typedef int int_least16_t;
typedef long int int_least32_t;
__extension__ 
#line 60
typedef long long int int_least64_t;


typedef unsigned char uint_least8_t;
typedef unsigned int uint_least16_t;
typedef unsigned long int uint_least32_t;
__extension__ 
#line 66
typedef unsigned long long int uint_least64_t;

typedef signed char int_fast8_t;
typedef int int_fast16_t;
typedef long int int_fast32_t;
__extension__ 
#line 75
typedef long long int int_fast64_t;


typedef unsigned char uint_fast8_t;
typedef unsigned int uint_fast16_t;
typedef unsigned long int uint_fast32_t;
__extension__ 
#line 81
typedef unsigned long long int uint_fast64_t;

typedef int16_t intptr_t;
typedef uint16_t uintptr_t;



__extension__ 
#line 97
typedef long long int intmax_t;
__extension__ 
#line 98
typedef unsigned long long int uintmax_t;
# 281 "/usr/lib/ncc/nesc_nx.h"
static __inline uint8_t __nesc_ntoh_uint8(const void * source)  ;




static __inline uint8_t __nesc_hton_uint8(void * target, uint8_t value)  ;
#line 304
static inline uint8_t __nesc_bf_decode8(const uint8_t *msg, unsigned offset, uint8_t length)  ;
#line 304
static inline void __nesc_bf_encode8(uint8_t *msg, unsigned offset, uint8_t length, uint8_t x)  ;
#line 304
static __inline uint8_t __nesc_ntohbf_uint8(const void *source, unsigned offset, uint8_t length)  ;
#line 304
static __inline uint8_t __nesc_htonbf_uint8(void *target, unsigned offset, uint8_t length, uint8_t value)  ;

static __inline uint16_t __nesc_ntoh_uint16(const void * source)  ;

static __inline uint16_t __nesc_hton_uint16(void * target, uint16_t value)  ;
#line 335
static inline uint16_t __nesc_bf_decode16(const uint8_t *msg, unsigned offset, uint8_t length)  ;
#line 335
static inline void __nesc_bf_encode16(uint8_t *msg, unsigned offset, uint8_t length, uint16_t x)  ;
#line 335
static __inline uint16_t __nesc_ntohbf_uint16(const void *source, unsigned offset, uint8_t length)  ;
#line 335
static __inline uint16_t __nesc_htonbf_uint16(void *target, unsigned offset, uint8_t length, uint16_t value)  ;

static __inline uint32_t __nesc_ntoh_uint32(const void * source)  ;


static __inline uint32_t __nesc_hton_uint32(void * target, uint32_t value)  ;
#line 372
static __inline int32_t __nesc_ntoh_int32(const void * source)  ;
#line 372
static __inline int32_t __nesc_hton_int32(void * target, int32_t value)  ;
#line 431
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[1]; } __attribute__((packed)) nx_int8_t;typedef int8_t __nesc_nxbase_nx_int8_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[2]; } __attribute__((packed)) nx_int16_t;typedef int16_t __nesc_nxbase_nx_int16_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[4]; } __attribute__((packed)) nx_int32_t;typedef int32_t __nesc_nxbase_nx_int32_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[8]; } __attribute__((packed)) nx_int64_t;typedef int64_t __nesc_nxbase_nx_int64_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[1]; } __attribute__((packed)) nx_uint8_t;typedef uint8_t __nesc_nxbase_nx_uint8_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[2]; } __attribute__((packed)) nx_uint16_t;typedef uint16_t __nesc_nxbase_nx_uint16_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[4]; } __attribute__((packed)) nx_uint32_t;typedef uint32_t __nesc_nxbase_nx_uint32_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[8]; } __attribute__((packed)) nx_uint64_t;typedef uint64_t __nesc_nxbase_nx_uint64_t  ;


typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[1]; } __attribute__((packed)) nxle_int8_t;typedef int8_t __nesc_nxbase_nxle_int8_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[2]; } __attribute__((packed)) nxle_int16_t;typedef int16_t __nesc_nxbase_nxle_int16_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[4]; } __attribute__((packed)) nxle_int32_t;typedef int32_t __nesc_nxbase_nxle_int32_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[8]; } __attribute__((packed)) nxle_int64_t;typedef int64_t __nesc_nxbase_nxle_int64_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[1]; } __attribute__((packed)) nxle_uint8_t;typedef uint8_t __nesc_nxbase_nxle_uint8_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[2]; } __attribute__((packed)) nxle_uint16_t;typedef uint16_t __nesc_nxbase_nxle_uint16_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[4]; } __attribute__((packed)) nxle_uint32_t;typedef uint32_t __nesc_nxbase_nxle_uint32_t  ;
typedef struct { unsigned char nxdata[8]; } __attribute__((packed)) nxle_uint64_t;typedef uint64_t __nesc_nxbase_nxle_uint64_t  ;
```

Comment: That looks like a *preprocessed* file. The source file have been run through the preprocessor so it contains all included header files. The only ways to "separate" the different parts is by the line starting with `#` followed by a line-number and a file-name.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad since asking "why" a preprocessed file looks obfuscated is essentially a question about human perception, not programming

Comment: The program you have posted here is a preprocessed file that is output by the nescc compiler of TinyOS. Basically when you write a TinyOS program in nesc, you compile it with nescc and get as output an app.c file which is in C. You then proceed to compile app.c with the usual tools (e.g msp430-gcc) and then upload your image to your chip